# Is there any way to reduce the memory in my Tensorflow CNN Model?

Tags: image, tensorflow, model, conv-neural-network

Hi currently in making new model I have some memory struggling.
I am doing summation between outputs of previous layers.
But it takes so much computation because it keeps allocating new memories I think.

print(max2.shape) = (None,8,8,96)

```
...
c6  = layers.DepthwiseConv2D(kernel_size = (3,3), depth_multiplier = 1, padding = 'same', activation = 'relu')(max2)
c7  = layers.DepthwiseConv2D(kernel_size = (3,3), depth_multiplier = 1, padding = 'same', activation = 'relu')(max2)
# Concat All the Depthwised outputs
layer3_output_list = [c0,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7]
layer3 = layers.Concatenate(axis = -1)(layer3_output_list)


# Add R's G's B's 
add_list = []
for i in range(layer3.shape[3]):
    if i%6 == 0:
        x = layers.Add()([layer3[:, :, :, i:i+1],layer3[:, :, :, i+3:i+4]])
        y = layers.Add()([layer3[:, :, :, i+1:i+2],layer3[:, :, :, i+4:i+5]])
        z = layers.Add()([layer3[:, :, :, i+2:i+3],layer3[:, :, :, i+5:i+6]])
        add_list.append(x)
        add_list.append(y)
        add_list.append(z)


layer3 = layers.Concatenate(axis = -1)(add_list)
```

print(layer3.shape) = (None,8,8,768)

```
max3 = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2))(layer3)

flatten = layers.Flatten()(max3)
```

is there any way to make this use less memory?
Do I have to make customized Layer for this?

**In Addition**
To explain about the for loops, with the result of layer3, I want to do sum between certain outcome "(ADD([layer3, layer3])" and add there Channels

**Currently**
I'm doing summation between (ith, i+3th) and (i+1th, i+4th) and (i+2th, i+5th) but I think I will change how i do summation later on

[image: my model]

Comment: You are creating layers in a loop. Can you give an standalone example of what `layer3` output looks like and what you want to achieve as output.

Comment: @vijayachandranmariappan Yes I have add the shape of the layer3 and what I want to do. thank you

Comment: @vijayachandranmariappan I'm sorry. I have changed the output shape of layer3. also added shape of max2 which is input shape for c0,c1,c2,,.....c6,c7.
what i am trying to do is, let's say, x represent R y represent G z represent B. and layer3[:, :, :, i:i+1] represent R at ith layer and layer3[:, :, :, i+3:i+4] represent R at i+3th layer. and I want to add those two R's. y and z is same but only different that y is for G and z is for B

Comment: What is the expected output size of R, G, B?

Comment: @vijayachandranmariappan for x it is (none,8,8,1) y is (none,8,8,1) z is (none,8,8,1) 
and after concatenating (none,8,8,768) and after pooling, (none,4,4,768) 

the dataset is cifar10. just in case I will attach my whole model code.

Answer (score 0):

Created a new layer that does the channel addition:

```
class ChannelAdd(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self,offset=3, **kwargs):
        super(ChannelAdd, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.offset = offset
    def call(self, inputs):
        s_ch = inputs + tf.roll(inputs, shift=-self.offset, axis=-1) 
        x = s_ch[:,:,:,::6]
        y = s_ch[:,:,:,1::6]
        z = s_ch[:,:,:,2::6]
        concat = tf.concat([x[...,tf.newaxis], y[...,tf.newaxis], z[...,tf.newaxis]], axis=-1)
        concat = tf.reshape(concat, [tf.shape(inputs)[0],tf.shape(inputs)[1],tf.shape(inputs)[2],-1])
        return concat
```

The model:

```
layer3 = keras.Input(shape=(8,8,768))

xyz = ChannelAdd()(layer3)

model = keras.Model(inputs=layer3, outputs=xyz)
```

Testing the model:

Creating a special input array easy for testing, where the channel contains the channel number: Channel 0 contains all 0s, 1 all 1s and so on

```
a = tf.zeros(shape=(5,8,8,1))
inputs = tf.concat([a,a+1,a+2], axis=-1)
for i in range(255):
    inputs = tf.concat([inputs, a+3*(i+1),a+3*(i+1)+1,a+3*(i+1)+2], axis=-1)
```

Output:

```
outputs = model(inputs)
outputs.shape
#[5, 8, 8, 384]

outputs[:,:,:,:6]
#check first 6 channels
array([[[[ 3.,  5.,  7., 15., 17., 19.],
     [ 3.,  5.,  7., 15., 17., 19.],
     [ 3.,  5.,  7., 15., 17., 19.],
     ...,
```

Comment: I think I have not said what I want properly. the result that I want from input (none,8,8,768) and after the layer, is (none, 8,8,256) . because what i wanted is to add..... let's say there is index (for channel, the 768) for output (none,8,8,768). and I want to add [0]+[3],[1]+[4],[2]+[5],[6]+[9],[7]+[10],[8]+[11],[12]+[15],.... and so on....

Comment: oh sorry it is suppose to be (none,8,8,384) not (none,8,8,256) which is the output shape of "[0]+[3],[1]+[4],[2]+[5],[6]+[9],[7]+[10],[8]+[11],[12]+[15]....." of this sum and concatenate. your output shape at concatenate_4 is (None, 8,8,3) But I need (none,8,8,384)

Comment: I have re-added the pho of my model which i have deleted yesterday

Comment: "[0]+[3],[1]+[4],[2]+[5],[6]+[9],[7]+[10],[8]+[11],[12]+[15]....."  output channel shape is 768 and not 384

Comment: the input is (8,8.,768). which means it was 768 different channels. and from those channels I want to do summation in channelwise. so, sum with 0th channel and 3rd channel. 1st channel and 4th channel. 2nd channel and 5th channel... and 6th +9th, 7th+10th.... and so on. So doing sum in channel wise with interval(interval is 3 because input shape's channel order will be RGBRGBRGBRGBRGB and i want to make R+R, G+G,B+B -> 0th 3rd(R), 1+4(G),2+5(B), 6+9(R)7+10(G)8+11(B)) so adding two channels will make 768 channel into 384. that's what I intended.... If my explanation is not enough tell me please

Comment: Thank you very much I have no clue about how does these code works. 
can you give me brief explanation about s_ch = inputs + tf.roll(~~~), x = ,,,::6, tf.concate, tf.reshape actually do? I never seen x[...,newaxis] or tf.roll

Comment: did it solve the problem?. The reason I created a `special input` is that its easy to understand what's happening at each level. In `return concat` , you can substitute it with `return s_ch` to check what that particular line does.

Answer (score 0):

Now, what you are doing is, as much as I understand the problem you are adding the same channels like (G+G+G+G+...) and then (R+R+R+R+...), etc... I did the code which is pretty much doing the same as yours. Still, with a different strategy, first, we need to split the input according to 3 channels like we saw (R, G, B), and then we will add the channels accordingly (R->R, G->G, B->B)... I have written a code that is pretty much doing the same as yours, but without for loops...

```
Let suppose I have input x...
x = tf.random.normal((1,80,80,768))
#Here, first I need to split the input according to RGB Sequence
splitted_image = tf.split(x, 256 , axis=-1)
#Check the shape of the splitted_image
print(splitted_image[0].shape)
```

```
TensorShape([1, 80, 80, 3])
```

```
#Now, we have to add the channels in such a way that maps (R->R, G->G, B->B)
add_ = tf.keras.layers.Add()([tf.cast(splitted_image[::2], dtype=tf.float32), tf.cast(splitted_image[1::2], dtype=tf.float32)])
#Now, the shape of the output tensor is 
print(add_.shape)
```

```
TensorShape([128, 1, 80, 80, 3])
```

```
#Now, we need to concatenate the inputs based on the last axis which is 3
concanated_output = tf.concat(tf.split(add_, 3 , axis=-1),axis=0)
#Output of the concatenated_output is
print(concatenated_output.shape)
```

```
TensorShape([384, 1, 80, 80, 1])
```

```
#Now, we need to set the arrangments of the axis using tf.Transpose

tf.transpose(concanated_output, perm=[1,2,3,0,4])
```

```
#As I compared the output of both the tensors from your method and mine method both are giving me the same results
```

```
tf.transpose(concanated_output, perm=[1,2,3,0,4])[0,:,:,0,0] == layer3[0,:,:,0]
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(80, 80), dtype=bool, numpy=
array([[ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
       ...,
       [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True]])>
```

**All in one GO** for implementing in `Keras.layer`

```
#for your model in one go 

split_layer = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x : tf.split(x, 256, axis=-1))(layer3)
add_layer = tf.keras.layers.Add()([tf.cast(split_layer[::2], 
                                           dtype=tf.float32), 
                                   tf.cast(split_layer[1::2], dtype=tf.float32)])
add_layer = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x : tf.split(x, 3 , axis=-1))(add_layer)
layer3 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate(add_layer, axis=0)
layer3 = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x : tf.transpose(x , perm=[1,2,3,0,4])[:,:,:,:,0])(layer3)
```

Output:

```
<KerasTensor: shape=(None, 80, 80, 384) dtype=float32 (created by layer 'lambda_1')>
```

**`For 2 Iterations`** Yours method took **`23 secs`** and mine took **`1.7`** secs.